# Can I use Django's template language to construct HTML for use in a JSON response field?

Tags: python, json, django

I have a scenario where I would like to return JSON from my view, normally this is pretty straight forward, however I need one of the attributes to be HTML, preferably constructed by the Django template language so I can take advantage of it's filters and other out-of-the-box functionality.

Is there a way to intercept the string that is generated by the Django template engine, and then access it within the view so it can be packaged up into an attribute of a JSON envelope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to "intercept" anything. Rendered Django templates are simply strings, and there is a [handy shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) to do exactly what you want:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
```